# Generate dynamic GraphQL Schema

Tags: api, graphql, api-design, graphql-js

I'm creating a system where the no. of columns in a table is not fixed. I'll explain with an example.

Consider a people table with 3 columns.

```
people
----------
id | name | email
```

This table will be exposed to a GraphQL API and I can query the table. In my system, the user will be able to add custom columns to the people table. Let's say they add a nationality column. When they do this, the nationality won't be available in the API because it is not defined in the Schema.

So how can I make my schema dynamic that allows the user to query the people table with every extra column they add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can query the information_schema table or a fields table and get the extra fields for the people table and then use the GraphQLObjectType to build out my schema rather than using SDL.

Answer (score 0):

this is not the answer to your question but the ***suggestion*** because creating dynamic columns in SQL doesn't look like a good idea to me. Instead of thinking how can you create dynamic schema I think you should rethink on your DB structure.

Instead of adding new columns in `Person` table you should have different table for your custom columns like create `person_columns` table like

```
person_columns
----------
id | people_id | column_name | column_value
```

so for every people you can have multiple columns and its corresponding values and you dont have to worry about dynamically creating your graphQL schema. (depending on your requirement you can add more columns to `person_columns` table for more control)

Comment: I've thought about this solution. Initially I developed something like this, But my column would be a foreign key in another table so that I don't have to repeat the column_name. But this poses some issues. I would have to do a CROSSTAB or PIVOT query to get the info I want in an efficient manner, which is very db costly. Also, I still will have to query the person_columns table to build the graphQL schema.